# CNN and LSTM for image captioning in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, conv-neural-network

I want to implement the following architecture in **Keras** for image captioning purpose but I am facing a lot of difficulties in connecting the output of **CNN** to the input of **LSTM**.

[image: The structure of DL net]

It is important to use the output of the CNN as the LSTM's input. Something like the following image.
[image: The structure 2]

I can make an LSTM or CNN separately but this structure is what I don't know how to build.
The image must be transformed into a feature description CNN and be inputted to the LSTM while the words of the caption in the vector representation insert into LSTM cells from the other way. This way cell number one is responsible for producing the first word and so on. I think both CNN and the LSTM must be trained at the same time.

By the way, it is not a school homework :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are familiar with the Tensorflow Keras API. I will implement the code in the following way.

**Assumptions:** `Vocab_size = 4000` and `input_image_size = (572,572,3)`.

```
vocab_size = 4000

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(572, 572, 3))

c0 = layers.Conv2D(64, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(inputs)
c1 = layers.Conv2D(64, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c0)  # This layer for concatenating in the expansive part
c2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c1)

c3 = layers.Conv2D(128, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c2)
c4 = layers.Conv2D(128, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c3)  # This layer for concatenating in the expansive part
c5 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c4)

c6 = layers.Conv2D(256, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c5)
c7 = layers.Conv2D(256, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c6)  # This layer for concatenating in the expansive part
c8 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c7)

c9 = layers.Conv2D(512, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c8)
c10 = layers.Conv2D(512, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c9)  # This layer for concatenating in the expansive part
c11 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c10)

fc1 = layers.Dense(4096)(c11)
fc2 = layers.Dense(4096)(fc1)

reshape = layers.Reshape((64, 4096))(fc2)

rnn1 = layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(reshape)
rnn2 = layers.LSTM(64)(rnn1)

outputs = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(rnn2)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="caption_generate")


model.summary()
```

The important part here is to actually reshape your output from `4 dimensions` to `3 dimensions`. As the `LSTM` needs input in `3 dimensions`

```
reshape = layers.Reshape((64, 4096))(fc2)
```

The following code works and you should be able to use it.
I hope the answer serves you well.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I guess this is what I was looking for. Just one thing. How do you insert the images and the words separately into the LSTM? I mean, how to define where words should be inputted into each cell and how the result of Conv becomes the input of the first LSTM cell? Thanks again and I'm looking forward to your reply.

Comment: You will have to use the fit API. Just provide as your `x` images and `y` sentences using this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit. To understand how does the training of such a model works look at the following article. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning. The solution above provided implements the exact structure that you wished for.

Comment: Thanks man. I've already seen the link that you've given me but I guess I had a problem in knowing that the distinguishing between label and images is done this way